# Xampp / OS X - Unable to create temporary file. Check permissions in temporary files directory

Tags: php, macos, permissions, xampp, macos-sierra

I know that i am not the first one facing this problem, but all the answers didn't help me.

I am running OS X Siera 10.12.6 with Xampp 7.1.9-0 and trying to get a file list from a remote ftp server like this:

```
        $this->log('Changing to destination folder '.$config->folder.' on ftp server.',2);
        ftp_chdir($ftpConnection, $config->folder);
```

This is the returned error message:
    Warning: ftp_nlist(): Unable to create temporary file. Check permissions in temporary files directory. in /Users/foobar/Websites/local/foobar/class.importCsv.php on line 158

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/foobar/Websites/local/foobar/class.importCsv.php on line 160
```

When checking the output of phpinfo(); and looking for any given tmp-setting I get those paths / parameters that might be of interest:

```
upload_tmp_dir: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/
soap.wsdl_cache_dir /tmp    
TMPDIR: /var/folders/qq/912038129312390812903812093/T/
SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.f0uSENezH9/Listeners
upload_tmp_dir: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/    
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render: /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.aOzrWGVthG/Render
```

So I am going to change the folder permissions of all those folders:

```
chmod a+w /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp
chmod a+w /private/tmp/
chmod a+w /tmp
```

the last one is not working, it returns a "operation not permitted" (yes, I used sudo -i):

```
chmod a+w /var/folders/qq/9qwrj72x6sz73v2tgf7qddnh0000gn/T/
```

FYI: I just switched from the builtin Apache-PHP-System in OSX to Xampp so it definitely is some mis-configuration with Xampp.